# Produce an individually created email based on columns of information in a file

Tags: excel, vba, email

This file pulls in the different pieces of information
[image: info show in image below].

The textbox in the code shows what the email will look like before the code runs.

When I try to send the email, the error is

> "Loop without Do"

As well how do I allow for multiple addresses per email (Email1,email2,email3). Currently the code only pulls in Email1.

```vb
Sub send_mass_email()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim name, Email, Email2, Email3, GMEmail, body, subject, MTDRev, LMRev, SYSRevGrowth, MTDNMU, LMNMU, NMUChange, MTDLeads, LMLeads, LeadsChange, OSAvg, AvgNMU, AvgActivityMTD As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
    
    i = 2
    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""

        name = Range("B2").Value
        Email = Range("C2").Value
        Email2 = Range("D2").Value
        Email3 = Range("E2").Value
        GMEmail = Range("F2").Value
        body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
        subject = Range("G2").Value
        MTDRev = Range("H2").Value
        LMRev = Range("I2").Value
        SYSRevGrowth = Range("J2").Value
        MTDNMU = Range("K2").Value
        LMNMU = Range("L2").Value
        NMUChange = Range("M2").Value
        MTDLeads = Range("N2").Value
        LMLeads = Range("O2").Value
        LeadsChange = Range("P2").Value
        OSAvg = Range("Q2").Value
        AvgNMU = Range("R2").Value
        AvgActivityMTD = Range("S2").Value

        body = Replace(body, "B2", name) & "font.color=red"
        body = Replace(body, "H2", MTDRev)
        body = Replace(body, "I2", LMRev)
        body = Replace(body, "J2", SYSRevGrowth)
        body = Replace(body, "K2", MTDNMU)
        body = Replace(body, "L2", LMNMU)
        body = Replace(body, "M2", NMUChange)
        body = Replace(body, "N2", MTDLeads)
        body = Replace(body, "O2", LMLeads)
        body = Replace(body, "P2", LeadsChange)
        body = Replace(body, "Q2", OSAvg)
        body = Replace(body, "R2", AvgNMU)
        body = Replace(body, "S2", AvgActivityMTD)
        body = Replace(body, "X2", Title)
        body = Replace(body, "Y2", Date)
        
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
         .to = Email
         .to = Email2
         .to = Email3
         .to = GMEmail
         .subject = subject
         .body = body
         '.Attachments.Add ("") 'You can add files here
         .Display
         '.Send
    
        body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text 'reset body text
        
        i = i + 1
        
    Loop
    
    End If
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Email(s) Sent!"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: you need an `End With`

Comment: can you explain where and what I add?

Comment: after `'.send` put `End With` any logical structure you create has to be ended before the previous ends in this case it sees the `Loop` but since you're currently inside `With` it doesn't know what to do with that. IE: anything nested in something else must be contained entirely within it.

Comment: Your loop only reads values from row 2?

Answer (score 0):

Untested but this should get you closer:

```vb
Sub send_mass_email()

    Dim i As Integer, ws As Worksheet, col, c As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object, body As String, sTo As String
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    i = 2
    
    Do While ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        body = ws.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text & "font.color=red" '??

        'loop over the 3 potential address cells and concatenate any content
        For Each c In ws.Cells(i, "C").Resize(1, 3).Cells
            If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
                sTo = sTo & IIf(Len(sTo) > 0, ";", "") & c.Value 'build the "to" string
            End If
        Next c
        
        'you can skip all those intermediate variables and replace directly
        For Each col In Array(Split("B,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,X,Y", ","))  'loop array of column letters
            body = Replace(body, col & "2", ws.Cells(i, col).Value)         'replace tokens in body
        Next col
        
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
             .to = sTo
             .subject = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
             .body = body
             '.Attachments.Add ("") 'You can add files here
             .Display
             '.Send
        End With
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    MsgBox "Email(s) Sent!"
End Sub
```